# AIZU ONLINE JUDGEの0009でWrong Answerと表示された。

Tags: python, python3

[AIZU ONLINE JUDGE](http://judge.u-aizu.ac.jp/onlinejudge/)の0009の問題に苦戦し続けている人です。

[前回の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/45304/13972)で私がベストアンサーに選んだアルゴリズムを使って見たのですが、今度は「[Wrong Answer](http://judge.u-aizu.ac.jp/onlinejudge/review.jsp?rid=3049887#2)」となります。原因を調べるべく、以下のテスト用に用意した数字を入力して出力すると、

```
10
3
11
100
999999
```

以下のようになり、

```
1
1
2
31
333331
```

本来`n % i == 0`になると`False`になるはずの`flag`が`False`になっていないのがわかりました。

これの原因は何でしょうか？解決案も教えてください。

```
import math
import sys

sup = 1000000

is_prime = [0] * sup

count = [0] * sup

def sieve():
    is_prime[2] = 1
    for n in range(3,sup,2):
        flag = True
        for i in range(3, int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n) + 1)), 2):
            if n % i == 0:
                flag = False
                break
            if flag:
                is_prime[n] = 1

def precount():
    for n in range(2, sup):
        count[n] = count[n-1] + is_prime[n]

def main():
    sieve()
    precount()

    l = []

    for line in sys.stdin:
        l.append(int(line))

    for line in l:
         print(count[line])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

最初に、あなたのコードはいわゆるエラトステネスの篩(Sieve of Eratosthenes)とは全く関係ないので、関数名を`sieve`にするのはやめておいた方が良いですね。

さて、あなたのコードはこんな構造にするつもりなのですよね。

```
# 2は素数だよ
is_prime[2] = 1
# 3以上の奇数について
for n in range(3,sup,2):
|   # ここで`flag`に`n`が素数かどうかの判定結果を入れる
|   # ...
|   # 判定が真なら
|   if flag:
|   |   # `n`は素数だよ
|_  |_  is_prime[n] = 1
```

(`|_`はインデントの範囲を明示するために入れているので、当然そのままでは動きません。)

ところが実際のあなたのコードのインデントをよくみてください。

```
# 2は素数だよ
is_prime[2] = 1
# 3以上の奇数について
for n in range(3,sup,2):
|   flag = True
|   for i in range(3, int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n) + 1)), 2):
|   |   if n % i == 0:
|   |   |   flag = False
|   |   |_  break
|   |   if flag:
|_  |_  |_  is_prime[n] = 1
```

`if flag:`のブロックが`for i in`のブロックの中に入ってしまってます。つまり「`n`が素数かどうかの判定」をするためのループが終わってからでなく、ループの中で毎回`flag`を判定して真なら`is_prime[n] = 1`を実行してしまっています。(普通は`flag`が`False`になって`break`するまでなんども`flag`が`True`のまま繰り返すはずですよね。)

また√nが小さな値の場合、`for i in`のループは一度も実行されませんので、`is_prime[n] = 1`の行も全く実行されなくなります。`n`が比較的小さな値の場合に素数と判定されていないのはそのためです。

あなたの意図通りの処理をさせたいなら、インデントはこうなるはずです。

```
def sieve(): # この関数名はやめましょう…
    is_prime[2] = 1
    for n in range(3,sup,2):
        flag = True
        for i in range(3, int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n) + 1)), 2):
            if n % i == 0:
                flag = False
                break
        if flag:
            is_prime[n] = 1
```

ちなみに以前のあなたのコードよりはかなり高速化されているでしょうが、厳しい時間制限があるなら、通過するかどうかは微妙な実行時間がかかりますね。

Answer (score 0):

既に回答が出ていますので、蛇足ながら追加情報などを。

以下の様にすれば `flag` 変数は必要ないかと。

```
def sieve():
  is_prime[2] = 1
  for n in range(3, sup, 2):
    for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2):
      if n % i == 0:
        break
    else:
      is_prime[n] = 1
```